# Getting null data from SQL database - Android

Tags: android, sql

I have a SQL database that stores information from a server into it. This is my code that stores the data,

```
public void addCard(String did, String cid, String first, String second) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CARD_DID, did); // deck id
    values.put(KEY_CARD_CID, cid); // card id
    values.put(KEY_CARD_FIRST, first); 
    values.put(KEY_CARD_SECOND, second);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CARD, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

This is called in an activity with this code

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

db.addCard(json.getString(KEY_DID),
           json.getString(KEY_CID),
           KEY_FIRST,
           KEY_SECOND);
```

I don't get any error when I do this. The problem comes when I try to access the data. This is my function to access the data,

```
public HashMap<String, String> getCard(String cid){
    HashMap<String,String> card = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARD + " WHERE cid='" + cid + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        card.put("did", cursor.getString(1));
        card.put("cid", cursor.getString(2));
        card.put("first", cursor.getString(3));
        card.put("second", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return card
    return card;
}
```

I call this function using this code

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
HashMap card;
card = db.getCard(KEY_CID);
dlgAlert.setMessage(card.get("did") + " " + card.get("cid"));
```

When this code runs and the alert message pops up I get `null null` for a response.

I don't know if my error is in storing the data, or getting the data from the database.

**Create Table**

Code used to create table

```
String CREATE_DECK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARD + "("
    + KEY_CARD_ID      + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + KEY_CARD_DID     + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_CARD_CID     + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_CARD_FIRST   + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_CARD_SECOND  + " TEXT"  + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_DECK_TABLE);
```

Comment: post the code where you create the table in the database

Comment: Code used to create the table was added

Comment: Most suspicious part for me json.getString(KEY_DID), json.getString(KEY_CID). What are you passing, make sure they aren't nulls with Log.d()

Comment: How come it's KEY_CARD_FIRST when you create the table and KEY_CARD_F when you write to it? Are you sure that your all column names are the same in both places?

Comment: @Etun your comment made me suspicious too so I investigated and found that they were not null but I realized `card = db.getCard(KEY_CID);` was the problem because it should be `card = db.getCard(json.getString(KEY_CID));`. Thanks for the comment!